# javascript equivalent to angularjs $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to achieve the following output from default JavaScript (without using Angularjs.

I have this in my Angularjs route

`$state.go('app.show', {id: 3});`

I want to redirect to the same path only by using pure JavaScript, (the path I get in the browser is `#/app/show/3`

I did the following

`window.location.href = "#/app/show/3"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part after `#` is `location.hash` property, so it should be:

```
window.location.hash = '/app/show/3';
```

Comment: you are a life saver, it works like a charm, thanks heaps (...waiting another 4 mins to accept the answer.. )